# Changing property name across interface?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I'm trying to change the name of a property and change it across all classes that inherit that class (interface) without having to do it manually 1 by 1?

```
class ISomething { 
    string SomeString { get; }
}

class A : ISomething 
{
    public string SomeString => "Something 1";
}

class B : ISomething 
{
    public string SomeString => "Something 2";
}

class C : ISomething 
{
    public string SomeString => "Something 3";
}
```

Comment: There is no such magic, unless you use an extension such as ReSharper.

Answer (score 2):

If you change your "interface" to be an actual interface then you can just right-click ISomething.SomeString and rename it and it will change all the classes that implement it.

Currently, you can't do this because ISomething is a class. The implication of this is that SomeString of each derived class and SomeString of ISomething are not even related. You can't access ISomething.SomeString from A because its not a public property in ISomething. If the class had SomeString as a public property (try it by adding public to it) then the derived classes would warn you that their SomeString is hiding ISomething.SomeString.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio, highlight the variable/object that you wish to rename and right click the highlighted text.  Select the "Rename..." option from the menu.

[image]